# Input to object

Tags: javascript

My question is: How to migrate **`var x`** which is basically user input data to **`var person`** so user could change `person.firstName` by inputing data into `<input type="text" id="userInput" value="">` element. I am very new for JS concepts, so I would be appreciate for any help. Thank you.

```
var person = {
firstName : "John",
lastName : "Doe",
age : 30,
fullName : function() {
       return "My name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " I am " + this.age + " years old";
    }
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName (); // Result: My name is John Doe I am 30 yers old

/* Input */
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can add the event `input` to your input field.
- Set the entered input (firstName) to your object `person`.

**Look this code snippet:**

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 30,
  fullName: function() {
    return "My name is " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName + " I am " + this.age + " years old";
  }
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName();

/* Input */
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  person.firstName = x;
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName();
}

document.getElementById("userInput").addEventListener('input', myFunction);
```

```html
<span id='demo'></span>

<p>User Input</p>
<input type="text" id="userInput" value="">
```

See? The object person is being updated automatically.

## Resource

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: It did its work! Pretty much what I have expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you say:

```
function updateFirstName() {
 person.firstName = document.getElementById("userInput").value; 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.fullName();
}
```